# Extract substring between two symbols in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, gsub, tweets

I'm trying to get a substring from a set of qouted retweets in a dataframe, where the substring appears as follows:

> RT @fireengineering: #Firefighter injured

I'd like to get the retweeted User's ScreenName, the string between the "@"  and the ":", for every row in my TweetText col and and them to a new col. I've tried to use gsub and regex in tidyverse to extract the username, with little avail:

```
FireExportF3 <- FireExport %>%
select(TweetID,ScreenName, TweetText) %>%
dplyr::filter(str_detect(TweetText, "RT"))

FireExportF3$QoutedUser <- FireExportF3 %>%
gsub("@([^;]*):", "\\1", TweetText)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

[image: FireExportF3]

when I run the function, it also says:

```
Error in gsub(., "@([^;]*):", "\\1", TweetText) : 
object 'TweetText' not found
```

If anyone could point out my error or suggest an alternative, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Use `gsub(".*@([^:]*):.*", "\\1", TweetText) `

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! The issue I did not clarify on, is that gsub does not recognise that TweetText is a col, which is why it's not extracting it correctly. I'll add this to the question:

Comment: Then also add the minimal code to repro the issue, too.

Comment: Try `FireExportF3$QoutedUser <- sub(".*@([^:]*):.*", "\\1", FireExportF3$TweetText)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked perfectly, thank you very much! Issue resolved